# ogr2ogr does not set osm_id for all multipolygons

Tags: gdal, openstreetmap, ogr2ogr, spatialite

I used ogr2ogr to convert from osm data (pbf) to spatialite :

```
ogr2ogr -progress -f SQLite -dsco spatialite=yes france.simple.spatialite france-latest.osm.pbf
```

then, a large part of the imported data misses osm_id

```
spatialite> select count(*) from multipolygons;
42287946
spatialite> select count(*) from multipolygons where osm_id is null;
42153385
```

any ideas why, and how to fix this ?

Comment: I edited the title a bit because this will happen with all outputformats and it affects only the multipolygon table. The background is that osm_id is not unique globally in the native OSM data. Osm_id of ways starts from #1 as well as in the relations table and therefore it is possible to get two polygons with the same osm_id: one from a closed way, another from a multipolygon relation. Unfortunately that makes also osm_id unsuitable as a primary key. User may not notice that because small amounts of data may not contain duplicate osm_ids.

Comment: osm2pgsql uses negative ids for multipolygon relations and positive ones for closed ways. Would that approach spoil anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only inspecting `osm_id` field. It seems you didn't inspect your `multipolygons` table.

On a local use case, I do :

```
ogrinfo -so france.simple.spatialite multipolygons
```

It returns

```
FID Column = OGC_FID
Geometry Column = GEOMETRY
osm_id: String (0.0)
osm_way_id: String (0.0)
name: String (0.0)
type: String (0.0)
...
```

So the identifiers are not only located on the `osm_id` but also in an `osm_way_id`.

Try :

```
select count(*) from multipolygons where osm_id is null AND osm_way_id is null;
```

It should return 0 records.

So, there is no need for fix.

Comment: Explained as a comment inside the osmconf.ini file: `[multipolygons]
# common attributes
# note: for multipolygons, osm_id=yes instanciates a osm_id field for the id of relations
# and a osm_way_id field for the id of closed ways. Both fields are exclusively set.` Also related to GDAL ticket http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5470